# Was Ronald responsible for starting the fire that killed Dennis McCaffrey?

Tags: plot-explanation, backdraft

In [*Backdraft*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101393/), the beginning of the film shows a firefighter (Dennis McCaffrey) killed while fighting a fire while his two young sons, Brian and Stephen witnessed it.

Brian and Steven are now adults and both firefighters.  The fire inspector takes Brian to a parole hearing for known arsonist, Ronald Bartel.  Ronald knows Brian's brother, Stephen as well as his late father.

> BRIAN:  Hey, do I know you?
>
> RONALD: Your dad did.
>
> BRIAN:  Who the hell is this guy?
>
> RONALD: (speaking to the fire inspector, whom he calls "shadow") Come
>   on, Shadow. He lost his dad to the animal...and you didn't even tell
>   him who he was coming to see? Tell him.

Ronald seemed to think that it was important that Brian knows who he is.  **Is there any evidence that Ronald started the fire that killed Dennis McCaffrey 20 years earlier?**

Comment: Heh, I just saw it on TV a few days ago and wondered about the exact same thing. I don't know why I didn't ask it as a question. But thanks for doing so.

Comment: I think if either the writer or director intended Ronald being responsible for that fire, it would have been revealed in the final cut.